# How to override .equals to compare 2 arraylists of custom object based on 2 attributes in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have an object called employee that has 2 attributes first name & last name the 2 employees are identical if both firstname and lastname are identical.

now I have 2 lists of employees I want to check if the list.equals(list)

previously I used ***id*** and I override the ***.equals*** as following

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {

            return false;
        }
        SMS sms = (SMS) obj;


        return sms.getID() == this.getID();


    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.getID() != null ? this.getID().hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }
```

### now I want to use a combination of firstname and lastname to compare instead of id.

Comment: Compare the first names and the last names, like you are comparing the IDs in your example. By the way, the trick with the `getClass()` is not recommended, because it breaks polymorphism.

Comment: And? Where is the problem with comparing these Strings?

Comment: I haven't updated hascode thats why it wasn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare firstName and lastName as you are comparing id in equals methods. Make sure you use equals to compare firstName and lastName instead of "==", assuming they are strings.

Also, if you are going to do that, make sure hashCode method is adjusted accordingly.